# Partnership Minyan?

Tags: heterodox, minyan

There are minyanim who self-identify as "partnership minyanim". Wikipdedia [gives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partnership_minyan) this definition of a partnership minyan:

> [A] prayer group that is both committed to maintaining halakhic standards and practices and also committed to including women in ritual leadership roles to the fullest extent possible within the boundaries of Jewish Law. This means that the minyan is made up of 10 men, men and women are separated by a mechitzah, and the traditional liturgy is used. However, women may fully participate in kriyat ha'Torah (Torah reading), including layning (chanting the text) and receiving aliyot, and may lead parts of the prayer service such as psukei d'zimrah and kabbalat Shabbat, which do not contain d'varim she bikedusha.

In terms of praxis, what differentiates these minyanim from an ordinary Orthodox minyan? Which of these factors are ubiquitous among partnership minyanim and which only exist in some partnership minyanim? What justification is given for these differences?

Comment: If I understand correctly, many Independent Minyanim—at least those in New York City— are primarily organized by the 20 and 30 somethings dremographic who tend to shy away from organized institutions. Some of the Minyan  are held at informal locations including homes where the group may stay after services for  Shabbos dinner

Answer (score 2):

I attended a partnership minyan Friday night.  This is something new in my city and the organizers are still working out details.  Here is what I learned there.

The group formed after a conference session about (maybe organized by) [JOFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_Orthodox_Feminist_Alliance).  Their intention is to follow the guidelines/precedents from that organization.  The service I attended was a normal Orthodox service (from the Koren siddur) without any liturgical alterations.  (For example, they did not insert the imahot into the amidah or anything like that.)  There was a mechitzah.  A woman led kabbalat shabbat and another woman gave a d'var torah; men led mincha and ma'ariv.  One of the organizers told me that in the future they might allow women to lead ma'ariv (it's done elsewhere, he said), but he didn't feel the local community is ready for that yet.  The vast majority of the attendees Friday night were from a few local Orthodox synagogues.  I believe I was the only Reform Jew present.

This group has not yet held a Shabbat morning service, but the organizer told me that women will be able to lein.  I didn't ask, but I understand that women having aliyot is also done.  We talked about Shira Chadisha in Jerusalem, where I've seen women have aliyot, and he said I should expect about the same as what they do.

I didn't ask the organizer of this minyan about sources or justifications.  At Shira Chadisha some years ago I was given an explanation that pretty much matches the Wikipedia passage quoted in the question.  There I saw a woman lead p'sukei d'zimra, and I saw women lein and receive aliyot.  The rest of the Shabbat morning service was led by men.

Answer (score 1):

Partnership minyanim give women aliyot or let them lein, based on the Gemara in megillah (stressing the *"women can ..."* part, but not the *"...but they shouldn't"* part.)

They wait for ten women's presence because, well because it feels nicer that way.

And they let a woman be chazan for any part that you could skip altogether if you were in a rush.

Comment: Note the ellipse in the "women can..." part is "women can count for the seven" not "women can get an Aliyah". Both halves of the Gemara are agreeing she shouldn't.

Comment: @DoubleAA What does counting for the seven mean if not reading from the Torah?

Comment: @magicker הכל עולין in the sense of "all get aliyot" is a lashon lechatchila, but in the sense of "all count to the 7" is a lashon bedieved (that's generally how the Talmud reads present and past tense legal statements)

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not sure I understand. You're saying that הכל עולין stam is לכתחילה, but with the extra words, הכל עולין למנין שבעה, it's now בדיעבד? (I'm well aware of explanations for this baraita and the accompanying tosefta that make it בדיעבד, but I don't understand the way you've phrased things.)

Comment: @magicker72 does "*olin*" in this context mean "they may ascend", or does it mean "they count." (*Oleh leminyan* -- it is included in the count.) One of the many points debated ad infinitum on this phrase.

Comment: @Shalom The Talmud never uses עלה like we do "to ascend [to the torah and read]". It always uses קרא for getting 'an aliyah' to the torah. Like a few pages earlier רב הונא קרי בכהני

Comment: @magicker72 Some people mistranslate הכל עולין למנין שבעה as "all can get aliyot towards the 7" which sounds lechatchila (cf. chullin 2a), but the better translation is "all [who have read] count towards the 7" which sounds bedieved. (I believe this point was made by RKJWieder)

Comment: It's been years since I looked at this stuff but I remember this article from Netuim sounding refreshingly like it didn't have an agenda https://www.herzog.ac.il/vtc/tvunot/netuim/netuim20_baras.pdf

Comment: @DoubleAA still it seems a bit funny; normally you'd say "don't do X, but bedieved it's kosher"; vs. "bedieved X is kosher, but don't do it." I wish the braisa had fleshed out the enigmatic sentence a bit more! (Yes, welcome to Torah shebe'al peh.)

Comment: @Shalom See the article in Netuim about how different parallel statements are adjoined to each other using אבל אמרו חכמים. Your question only comes up because you assume they were composed in that order together originally.